# Return String from Future Object

Tags: string, asynchronous, dart, future

I am trying to fetch html page via localproxy to parse and get urls from it. I can't find any library which works without Future in Dart. So i have difficulty returning String from a Future Object. Below is full code of dart file.

```
import 'package:universal_html/driver.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_universal/html.dart';

String proxyUrl='http://localhost/php-proxy/index.php?q=';
String hallTicketUrl='http://www.ignou.ac.in/ignou/studentzone/results/6';

Future<String> getList()async{
  final driver = HtmlDriver();
  await driver.setDocumentFromUri(Uri.parse(proxyUrl+hallTicketUrl));
  final items = driver.document.querySelectorAll('.middleconten2column a');

  Element urls=Element.tag('urls');
  items.forEach((item)=>urls.append(Element.tag('url')
                        ..setAttribute('href',item.getAttribute('href'))
                        ..text=item.text
                        )
        );
  print('${items.length} items found');

return Future.value(urls.outerHtml);
}

String Handler(String app){
    switch(app){
       case 'list': return getList() as String;
}
return "";
}

main(){
    print(Handler('list'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood what the `async` keyword does to methods. When a method are marked as `async` it will always automatically returns a Future of something. That is the reason why you need to specify e.g. `Future<String>` as the return type.

But because the creation are done "automatically" you don't really need to do the following:

```
return Future.value(urls.outerHtml);
```

But can just do:

```
return urls.outerHtml;
```

After this your have discovered the problem with using asynchronous programming where everything in your call stack needs to be marked as `async` since you have an `await` somewhere in your code.

I have fixed your code so it now hope it works correctly with all the future stuff:

```
import 'package:universal_html/driver.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_universal/html.dart';

String proxyUrl = 'http://localhost/php-proxy/index.php?q=';
String hallTicketUrl = 'http://www.ignou.ac.in/ignou/studentzone/results/6';

Future<String> getList() async {
  final driver = HtmlDriver();
  await driver.setDocumentFromUri(Uri.parse(proxyUrl + hallTicketUrl));
  final items = driver.document.querySelectorAll('.middleconten2column a');

  Element urls = Element.tag('urls');
  items.forEach((item) => urls.append(Element.tag('url')
    ..setAttribute('href', item.getAttribute('href'))
    ..text = item.text));
  print('${items.length} items found');

  return urls.outerHtml;
}

Future<String> Handler(String app) async {
  switch (app) {
    case 'list':
      return await getList();
  }
  return "";
}

main() async {
  print(await Handler('list'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks I learned new things. But still i can't understand how can i use it everywhere by making class/library of it i.e. in command-line, javascript and in server programs. e.g. someone called an api on server and handler handles request, how can it return xml/json independently from Future Object.

Comment: I tried with shelf server and cant assign the same handler('list') output to response.

Comment: shelf.Response _echoRequest(shelf.Request request){
    shelf.Response.ok('Request for "${request.url}"\n'+ht.handler('list'));
}

Comment: Please update your question with details about your new problem or create a new question. It is difficult to help you without any context of your code.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59090393/server-response-with-output-from-future-object

Comment: Do you need more information before you can accept my answer?

Comment: Future.value is what I was looking for, thanks!