# Server response with output from Future Object

Tags: dart, server, future, dart-shelf

i created a async/await function in another file thus its handler is returning a Future Object. Now i can't understand how to give response to client with content of that Future Object in Dart. I am using basic dart server with shelf package.Below is code where ht.handler('list') returns a Future Object and i want to send that string to client as response. But i am getting internal server error.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:args/args.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart' as shelf;
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as io;
import 'HallTicket.dart' as ht;

// For Google Cloud Run, set _hostname to '0.0.0.0'.
const _hostname = 'localhost';

main(List<String> args) async {
  var parser = ArgParser()..addOption('port', abbr: 'p');
  var result = parser.parse(args);

  // For Google Cloud Run, we respect the PORT environment variable
  var portStr = result['port'] ?? Platform.environment['PORT'] ?? '8080';
  var port = int.tryParse(portStr);

  if (port == null) {
    stdout.writeln('Could not parse port value "$portStr" into a number.');
    // 64: command line usage error
    exitCode = 64;
    return;
  }

  var handler = const shelf.Pipeline()
      .addMiddleware(shelf.logRequests())
      .addHandler(_echoRequest);

  var server = await io.serve(handler, _hostname, port);
  print('Serving at http://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
}

Future<shelf.Response> _echoRequest(shelf.Request request)async{
    shelf.Response.ok('Request for "${request.url}"\n'+await ht.handler('list'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analyzer gives your the following warning for your `_echoRequest` method:

> info: This function has a return type of 'Future', but
>   doesn't end with a return statement.

And if you check the requirement for `addHandler` you will see it expects a handler to be returned.

So you need to add the return which makes it work on my machine:

```
Future<shelf.Response> _echoRequest(shelf.Request request) async {
  return shelf.Response.ok(
      'Request for "${request.url}"\n' + await ht.handler('list2'),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by downloading? In my Firefox browser it just show the response.

Comment: In firefox it detected it as application/octet-stream. Still downloading it as file.

Comment: Sounds like this which are documented on the `shelf.Response.ok` method: "If [encoding] is passed, the "encoding" field of the Content-Type header in [headers] will be set appropriately. If there is no existing Content-Type header, it will be set to "application/octet-stream"."

Comment: Updated my answer so it shows how to set Content-Type.